# label_keys type error on DNNCLassifier Tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to embed labels into a DNNClassifier model in Tensorflow.
Unlike the documentation example, [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier#class_tfcontriblearndnnclassifier) , I get the following error message:

```
label_keys_values = ["satan", "ipsweep", "nmap", "portsweep"]  
m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(model_dir=model_dir,
                                  feature_columns=deep_columns,
                                  n_classes=4,
                                  hidden_units=[12, 4],
                                  label_keys=label_keys_values)
m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
```

> File "embedding_model_probe.py", line 118, in 
>       m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 281, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 430, in fit
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 927, in _train_model
>       model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1132, in _get_train_ops
>       return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1103, in _call_model_fn
>       model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 180, in _dnn_model_fn
>       logits=logits)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py", line 1004, in create_model_fn_ops
>       labels = self._transform_labels(mode=mode, labels=labels)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py", line 1033, in _transform_labels
>       "label_ids": table.lookup(labels_tensor),
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lookup/lookup_ops.py", line 179, in lookup
>       (self._key_dtype, keys.dtype))
>     TypeError: Signature mismatch. Keys must be dtype

< dtype: 'string'>, got < dtype: 'int64'>

On the other hand, if I make the `label_key_values` column a `numpy.array`, I will get the following error:

```
label_keys_values = np.array(["satan", "ipsweep", "nmap", "portsweep"], dtype='string')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "embedding_model_probe.py", line 116, in 
>       label_keys=label_keys_values)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 337, in **init**
>       label_keys=label_keys),
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py", line 331, in multi_class_head
>       label_keys=label_keys)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py", line 986, in **init**
>       if label_keys and len(label_keys) != n_classes:
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. As the official documentation says [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier) :

"If the user specifies label_keys in constructor, labels must be strings from the label_keys vocabulary."

In my case, I transformed the label column from the training and testing set into an one-hot vector(integer values) and the values from `label_keys_values` array did not match with them.